# Non blocking Jersey async resource with Jetty

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0, jetty-9

Using Jersey (2.32) with Jetty(9.4.35.v20201120) and have a question if Jersey makes use on Jetty's non blocking write capabilities for async resources?

Reading a fairly old and good article about Jetty non-blocking IO (https://webtide.com/servlet-3-1-async-io-and-jetty/) that describes how Jetty does it.

When debugging its *seems* like Jersey is using the blocking outputstream writes.

Reason for asking is that I have observed from production that our small pool compute threads tend to get stuck on blocking IO, and thus can get exhausted.

Comment: Jersey does offer an [asynchronous api](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10103)

Comment: Yes I know, the question is if that api make full use of jetty's non-blocking io capabilities

Comment: It makes use of the asynchronous api provided by the servlet specification. So if that is what you are referring to, then yes it does.